# Are $\phi(X^2)$ and $\psi(Y^2)$ always independent where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are Borel-Measurable functions (X,Y are any two RVs)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, borel-sets, borel-measures

In **An Introduction to Probability and Statistics** by Vijay K. **Rohatgi** and Ehsanes **Saleh** 2e, Page no 121, it is shown that if X, Y be two RVs with joint PDF, $f(x,y)$= $\frac{1+xy}{4} $, $|x|<1$ and $|y|<1 $, then X and Y are not independent but the RVs $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent, the concluding remark says:

> Note that $\phi(X^2)$ and $\psi(Y^2)$ are independent where $\phi$ and
>   $\psi$ are Borel-Measurable functions
>   (X and Y are RVs)

Is it a general statement or just a comment valid for the previous question because though it seems like an important result yet it is not mentioned as a theorem. If it is indeed general, how to proceed for a proof?

Comment: There is no chance this remark applies in general case. For instance, it is easy to come up with a counter-example with $Y=X$.

Comment: For any pair of independent random variables, any functions of each are independent.  This apples as well to $X^2$ and $Y^2$, given to be independent.